# could any one help me to rectify Error with bigcommerce CLI

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to bigcommerce. I have followed Stencil CLI comments to work with local copy of theme. 
while using **STENCIL BUNDLE** comment i am getting following error. can any one help me to rectify it.

stencil bundle

Validating theme...

/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/stencil-bundle.js:290

```
        throw err;
        ^
```

Error: **Your theme's schema.json has errors:**

schema[5].settings[1].options[0].value should NOT be shorter than 1 characters
    at validateJsonSchema

(/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/bundle-validator.js:134:16)
    at BundleValidator.validateThemeSchema (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/bundle-validator.js:78:23)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
    at replenish (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
    at eachOfLimit (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1041:24)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1046:16
    at _parallel (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3879:5)
    at Object.series (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4735:5)
    at BundleValidator.validateTheme (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/bundle-validator.js:55:11)
    at Bundle.validateTheme (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/stencil-bundle.js:288:20)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
    at replenish (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
    at eachOfLimit (/home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1041:24)
    at /home/innoppl/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1046:16

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to errors when the schema.json or schemaTranslations.json file have been removed or modified, are you using the [base Cornerstone theme](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/)? Could you add any relevant schema code in your post? If the schema.json should be the same as the base Cornerstone theme, I'd verify this against the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/schema.json).

Since [Stencil CLI 2.0](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#posts/stencil-cli-2-0-0-release), part of the bundle process now validates a schemaTranlsations.json file which has been included since Cornerstone 4.5.1.